# NumberFormatter::PERCENT with decimals

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following expression in order to get numbers from DB, made some calculations and export as a PERCENT, but I get the without decimals.
How can I add decimals?

```
<?php  $fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::PERCENT );
      echo $fmt->format(($data['budget'] - (((($data['budget'] / 1.67) - $data['id_orcmontagem']) * 1.6) + $data['id_orcmontagem'])) /  $data['budget'])."\n"; ?>
```

Comment: *PERCENT* is the wrong one. `In order to format percentages, create a locale-specific formatter with percentage format type. With this formatter, a decimal fraction such as 0.75 is displayed as 75%.`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line and everything works now

```
numfmt_set_attribute($fmt, NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
```